# Spring between two draggable surfaces in famo.us

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I'm trying to implement two surfaces, connected with a spring, that would react to drag in famo.us. So far I have setup the surfaces, can drag those, have a spring that interacts during the loading of the page, but not on drag. So the questions are a) how should I connect two surfaces with a spring and b) how do I update the physics when I drag one surface so that the other surface would follow the dragged surface?

The code I so far have is this

```
define(function(require) {

  var Engine          = require('famous/core/Engine');
  var Surface         = require('famous/core/Surface');
  var StateModifier   = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
  var PhysicsEngine   = require('famous/physics/PhysicsEngine');
  var Circle          = require('famous/physics/bodies/Circle');
  var Draggable       = require('famous/modifiers/Draggable');
  var Spring          = require('famous/physics/forces/Spring');
  var Vector          = require('famous/math/Vector');

  var context = Engine.createContext();
  var physicsEngine = new PhysicsEngine();

  var ball = new Surface ({
    size: [100,100],
    properties: {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          borderRadius: '50px'
    }
  });

  var ball2 = new Surface ({
    size: [100,100],
    properties: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          borderRadius: '50px'
    }
  });

  var draggable = new Draggable();
  var draggable2 = new Draggable();

  ball.state = new StateModifier({origin:[0.2,0.2]});
  ball2.state = new StateModifier({origin:[0.3,0.3]});

  ball.particle = new Circle({radius:100});
  ball2.particle = new Circle({radius:100});

  var spring = new Spring({
      anchor:         ball.particle,
      period:         400,  // <= Play with these values :-)
      dampingRatio:   0.07, // <=
      length:         50
  });
//    var spring2 = new Spring({anchor: ball2.particle});

//    physicsEngine.attach(spring, ball2.particle);
//    physicsEngine.attach(spring2, ball.particle);

  draggable.subscribe(ball);
  draggable2.subscribe(ball2);

  draggable.on('update', function() {
      console.info('update');
      ball2.particle.applyForce(new Vector(0, 0, -0.005 * 100));
//        ball.state.setTransform(ball.particle.getTransform())
//        ball.state.setTransform(ball.particle.getTransform())
//        ball.particle.setVelocity([0.001,0,0]);
//        physicsEngine.wake();
//        physicsEngine.step();
  });
  draggable2.on('update', function() {
//        ball2.particle.setVelocity([0.001,0,0]);
//        console.info('update');
//        physicsEngine.wake();
//        physicsEngine.step();
  });


  physicsEngine.attach(spring, ball2.particle);
//    spring.applyForce(ball.particle);
  physicsEngine.addBody(ball.particle);
  physicsEngine.addBody(ball2.particle);


//    ball.on("click",function(){
//      ball.particle.setVelocity([10,0,0]);
//    });
//
//    ball2.on("click",function(){
//      ball2.particle.setVelocity([0,10,0]);
//    });

  context.add(draggable).add(ball.state).add(ball);
  context.add(draggable2).add(ball2.state).add(ball2);

  Engine.on('prerender', function(){
    ball.state.setTransform(ball.particle.getTransform());
    ball2.state.setTransform(ball2.particle.getTransform());
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have a pretty good understanding of the PE thus far. I can still see a few places you can improve. Here is a working example of dragging with a spring attached. Although this implementation is not perfect yet, it should get you started.. If you start with dragging the red circle, everything works as expected.. Draggable has its own position, and so does particle. So when you grab the blue circle, there remains an offset in particle. Here is what will get you 95%..

Hope it helps..

```
var Engine          = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface         = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Transform       = require('famous/core/Transform');
var Modifier        = require('famous/core/Modifier');

var Draggable       = require('famous/modifiers/Draggable');

var PhysicsEngine   = require('famous/physics/PhysicsEngine');
var Circle          = require('famous/physics/bodies/Circle');
var Spring          = require('famous/physics/forces/Spring');

var context = Engine.createContext();
var physicsEngine = new PhysicsEngine();

var ball = new Surface ({
  size: [100,100],
  properties: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderRadius: '50px'
  }
});

var ball2 = new Surface ({
  size: [100,100],
  properties: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        borderRadius: '50px',
  }
});

ball.mod = new Modifier({origin:[0.5,0.5]});
ball.draggable = new Draggable();
ball.pipe(ball.draggable);
ball.particle = new Circle({radius:100});
ball.mod.transformFrom(function(){ return Transform.translate(0,0,0) });

ball.spring = new Spring({
  anchor:         ball.particle,
  period:         400,
  dampingRatio:   0.07,
  length:         50
});

ball2.mod = new Modifier({origin:[0.5,0.5]});
ball2.draggable = new Draggable();
ball2.pipe(ball2.draggable);
ball2.particle = new Circle({radius:100});
ball2.mod.transformFrom(function(){ return ball2.particle.getTransform()});

ball2.spring = new Spring({
  anchor:         ball2.particle,
  period:         400,
  dampingRatio:   0.07,
  length:         50
});

ball.draggable.on('start',function(){

  ball2.setProperties({pointerEvents:'none'});

  if (ball2.springID) physicsEngine.detach(ball2.springID);
  if (ball.springID) physicsEngine.detach(ball.springID);

  ball.springID = physicsEngine.attach(ball.spring, ball2.particle);
  ball2.springID = null;

  ball.mod.transformFrom(function(){ return Transform.translate(0,0,0) });
  ball2.mod.transformFrom(function(){ return ball2.particle.getTransform()});

})

ball.draggable.on('update', function() {
    pos = ball.draggable.getPosition();
    ball.particle.setPosition(pos);
});

ball.draggable.on('end', function() {
  ball2.setProperties({pointerEvents:'all'});
});

ball2.draggable.on('start',function(){

  ball.setProperties({pointerEvents:'none'});

  if (ball2.springID) physicsEngine.detach(ball2.springID);
  if (ball.springID) physicsEngine.detach(ball.springID);

  ball2.springID = physicsEngine.attach(ball2.spring, ball.particle);
  ball.springID = null;

  ball2.mod.transformFrom(function(){ return Transform.translate(0,0,0) });
  ball.mod.transformFrom(function(){ return ball.particle.getTransform()});

})

ball2.draggable.on('update', function() {
    pos = ball2.draggable.getPosition();
    ball2.particle.setPosition(pos);
});

ball2.draggable.on('end', function() {
  ball.setProperties({pointerEvents:'all'});
});

ball.springID = physicsEngine.attach(ball.spring, ball2.particle);

physicsEngine.addBody(ball.particle);
physicsEngine.addBody(ball2.particle);

context.add(ball.mod).add(ball.draggable).add(ball);
context.add(ball2.mod).add(ball2.draggable).add(ball2);
```